# Cannot find page table entry

Tags: assembly, memory-management, x86, operating-system, page-tables

I cannot find records in the page table/page directory for address **0xB8000**. It works correct and when I put some symbols into this memory region display shows it.

I’m in the protected mode, and paging is enabled. I’m using bochs.

**cr0** is 0xe0000011 or 1110 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 0001b,
**cr3** is 0x1000

[image]

**0xB8000** is equal **1011 1000 0000 0000 0000**b, so 10111000b is **index of page table**, it's equal **184**, index of **page directory** is **0**, offset is zero.

I go to 0x1000 of physical memory and I get first (index 0) item:
[image]

It is 0x2027 or 10 0000 0010 0111b so the physical address of the page table is 10b or 2. I need a content of 184th entry so I need to go to 184 * 4 + 2 = 738 = 0x2E2, but it's empty:
[image]

Btw I have three memory descriptors (memory from 0x0 to 0xFFFFFFFF):

```
null:
    0
code: 
    dw 0FFFFh           ; limit low
    dw 0                ; base low
    db 0                ; base middle
    db 10011010b        ; access
    db 11001111b        ; granularity
    db 0                ; base high

data:
    dw 0FFFFh           ; limit low (Same as code)
    dw 0                ; base low
    db 0                ; base middle
    db 10010010b        ; access
    db 11001111b        ; granularity
    db 0                ; base high
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It is 0x2027 or 10 0000 0010 0111b so the physical address of the page table is 10b or 2. I need a content of 184th entry so I need to go to 184 * 4 + 2 = 738 = 0x2E2, but it's empty:

It's 0x2027, so the physical address of the page table is **0x2000** (not 2). The 185th entry (entry number 184) will be at offset 0x2E0 in the page table and will have the physical address 0x22E0.

Note: You could shift the page directory entry (0x2027) to the right 12 places and say "it's physical page number 2", then multiply the page number by the size of a page (or shift it left 12 places) to find the physical address of the page. It's easier/faster to just mask off the lowest 12 bits instead (e.g. `physical_address_of_page_table = page_directory_entry & 0xFFFFF000;`), especially when doing it in your head with hexadecimal values (where you can just assume the last 3 digits are zeros).

Comment: @daniil_: I've read that BOCHS's built-in debugger is supposed to be able to print / dump page tables; it might have been able to remind you how to decode a page-directory entry.